# React setTransition() function causes two re-renders even though there is no state update in it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider the following code:

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useEffect, useTransition} from 'react';

function Item({name, _key})
{
   const [isPending, setTransition] = useTransition();
   const [updatingName, setUpdatingName] = useState(false);
   const nameInputElement = useRef();

   useEffect(() => {
      if (updatingName) {
         nameInputElement.current.focus();
      }
   }, [updatingName]);

   function onUpdateClick() {
      setUpdatingName(true);
   }

   function onCancelClick() {
      setUpdatingName(false);
   }

   console.log('rendering');

   return (
      <div>
         <input ref={nameInputElement} type="text" defaultValue={name} name="name"
         disabled={!updatingName} />

         {!updatingName
         ? <>
            <button key={1} type="button" onClick={onUpdateClick}>Update</button>
            <button key={2} type="submit" name="delete" value={_key}>Remove</button>
         </>
         : <>
            <button key={3} type="button" name="update" onClick={(e) => {
               setTransition(() => {})
            }}>Save</button>
            <button key={4} type="button" onClick={onCancelClick}>Cancel</button>
         </>}
      </div>
   )
}

function ItemList({title})
{
   return <>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <form method="post" onSubmit={(e) => {e.preventDefault()}}>
         <Item name={'small'} _key={0}></Item>
      </form>
   </>
}

export default ItemList;
```

CodeSandbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/embed/elegant-artem-6zx74r?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

When the `Save` button is clicked, `setTransition()` is called but there is absolutely no state updates in there — it's completely empty. Hence, I expect there to be no re-renders on the click of `Save`.

Surprisingly, however, when I click `Save`, I get to see not just one, but two `rendering` logs in the console.

**Why is this happening?** I consulted the React docs, but there is no mention of re-renders performed on `setTransition()`.

Comment: which version of React do you use?

Comment: @CptSosen 18.2.0

Answer (score 0):

enter the button into new component and it should not render twice(the button will render).
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-hooks-ohmf5t)

```
import { useTransition } from "react";

const Button = () => {
  const [isPending, setTransition] = useTransition();
  return (
    <button
      key={3}
      type="button"
      name="update"
      onClick={(e) => {
        setTransition(() => {
        });
      }}
    >
      Save
    </button>
  );
};
export default Button;
```